# Composition of function and transformation

Tags: functions

My question is the following-

> Given $f(x) = x^2$ and $(2,4)$ is a point on this parabola. The function is shifted $5$ to the left, given a horizontal stretch by a factor $1/3$, reflected over the $x$-axis, given a vertical stretch by a factor of $2$ and a vertical shift of $-3$. After all these transformations, what is the new equation and new image of the point $(2,4)$?

The answer I found was 
$$y= -\frac{2}{3}(x+5)^2 - 3$$
but I am not sure if my answer is correct or not.

My math teacher showed an answer: $$-2\{3(x+5)\}^2-3$$ 
and showed the mirror image of $(2,4)$ after solving will be $(-1,-8)$. But I am not confident about the answer and procedure that my teacher used and this mirror image point is not verified by the equation he showed. 
I am looking for a detailed explanation where the **transformed equation** will be verified by the **transformed mirror image point of $(2,4)$**

Also, isn't  the **transformed mirror image point of $(2,4)$** verified (after we put the values in the transformed equation) by the **transformed equation**??

Answer (score 1):

Translation by $5$ to the left: $x\to x+5$.
Horizontal stretch by $1/3$: $x\to 3x$, i.e. $(x+5)\to(3x+5)$.
Reflection in $x$-axis: $y\to -y$.
Vertical stretch by $2$: $y\to 2y$.
Translation by $3$ down: $y\to y-3$.

Combining: $$y=x^2\to y=(x+5)^2\to y=(3x+5)^2\to y=-(3x+5)^2\to y=-2(3x+5)^2\to \\y=-2(3x+5)^2-3$$So this is the correct answer.

The image of $(2,4)$ can be worked out as

$$(2,4)\to (-3,4)\to (-1,4)\to (-1,-4)\to(-1,-8)\to (-1,-11)$$